# Python 3 cx_freeze Win34GUI issue

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have used this compile.py setup quite a few times with great success. I just discovered after updating an app that it runs fine inside of python. When I freeze it, it wont run right and doesn't output any errors?

Here is my compile code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
     base = "Win32GUI"
setup( name = "MYAPP" , 
       version = "0.1" , 
       description = "MYAPP" , 
       executables = [Executable("MYAPP.py",
                                 icon = "s.ico", 
                                 base = base)] , )
```

When I remove the base = base line, the .exe launches with an output window and the app runs correctly. If I set the base = base to remove the output window, the application wont run right?

I believe the problem code to be the reporthook function of urllib.request.urlretrieve as it didn't start doing this until I tried to integrate this download progressbar. This is part of a for loop that runs for each file I am trying to download. It will download the 1st file then stop after it hits 100% only if I set base = base in the compile.py file...

I'm lost.

Thanks for any help!

```
def reporthook(blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
    percent = 0
    readsofar = blocknum * blocksize
    if totalsize > 0:
        percent = readsofar * 1e2 / totalsize
        if percent >= 100:
            percent = 100

        s = "\r%5.1f%% %*d / %d" % (
            percent, len(str(totalsize)), readsofar, totalsize)

        self.time['text'] = 'Downloading File: '+self.fn+'' + s

        if readsofar >= totalsize: # near the end
            sys.stderr.write("\n")
    else: # total size is unknown
        sys.stderr.write("read %d\n" % (readsofar,))

    #UPDATE PROGRESSBAR
    self.pb.config(mode="determinate")
    if percent > 0:
        self.dl_p = round(percent,0)
        self.pb['value'] = self.dl_p
        self.pb.update()
    if percent > 100:
        self.pb['value'] = 0
        self.pb.update()

urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgs, fileSavePath, reporthook)
```

Comment: Decent question but there's something weir going on with your code formatting. Can you remove the spaces between backticks please? A more readable question is likely to result in more replies.

Comment: Sorry, new on the site. Got to get used to the editor.

Comment: No problem, just trying to help. But one of the better first time questions I've seen in a long time, hence other people an I are giving you upvotes :) Keep up the good work!

Comment: So, I tried to compile the program with py2exe and this issue completely went away. I suspect it is something with cx_freeze doing it.

Comment: If you solved your own problem and can pinpoint what exactly went wrong, write up an answer, post it and accept it. It's allowed to accept your own answer, just so in the future someone with the same problem can more easily resolve his/her issue.

Comment: I didn't want to do that as I haven't figured out what was causing the original issue, just found a different way to compile the python script into an exe that doesn't exhibit the issue.

Comment: If you freeze it with the GUI base so there isn't a command prompt when you run it, you shouldn't write to `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr` at all. They are for the command prompt, so if you don't have a command prompt, they won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas K - That was the solution to the problem.

"If you freeze it with the GUI base so there isn't a command prompt when you run it, you shouldn't write to sys.stdout or sys.stderr at all. They are for the command prompt, so if you don't have a command prompt, they won't work. –  Thomas K 11 hours ago"

Thanks!